# Abstracting to a common interface

Tags: c#, class, interface

I have 2 derived objects, which both implement a common interface, I put this interface into a GUI, however the the GUI takes in 2 separate lists of the common interface depending on what button is pressed.

The two lists contain the two separate concrete classes, but abstracted as the interface, so the one form can modify the 2 different objects.

My problem is if I am storing them as the common interface, how do I look at them as there actual objects later on in my program, or can I store them as concrete objects and then convert them to the interface just so they can use my form and then change them back.

This is more of a design program than a coding question, are there any design patterns which look  at this?

Comment: Please post the classes and interface. Makes it easier to talk about it.

Answer (score 0):

Just cast it back to the concrete type.

Example:

```
var foo = commonInterfaceObject as ConcreteType;
if (foo != null)
{
    // work with concrete type here
}
```

If you want to put it back into the list of common interfaces, there's no need to cast back (since the ConcreteType implements the interface).

Example:

```
var interFaceList = new List<ICommonInterface>();

// add back
interFaceList(foo); // foo is your concrete type
```